# Counting data items in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have some data. It looks like this (but with several hundred objects in the array rather than three):

```
var data = [
{
    id: "1",
    name: "Name1",
    color: "Color1"
},
{
    id: "2",
    name: "Name2",
    color: "Color2"
},
{
    id: "1",
    name: "Name3",
    color: "Color3"
}
```

What I want to do is draw a rectangle which has a height that corresponds to the number of items in the data which have a certain `id` value. So, for example, if there were 300 items in the data array with an `id` of "1", then the rectangle would be 300 pixels tall.

Obviously I could loop through the array and count them up, but I want to know if there's an easier/shorter way in d3.js.

What I have in mind might look like this:

```
svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).enter()
    .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 800)
        .attr('y', 800)
        .attr('height', //SOME CODE HERE)
        .attr('width', 5)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do two things:

1) group your Id to get the count

2) set the count value as height attribute for `d3` rect

The below code will group your id by indexing it. The length of the `groupId` would be the count for common `id` inside your data:

```
var groupId = [];
var maxId = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var item = data[i];

    if (!groupId[item.id]){
        groupId[item.id] = [];
    }

    groupId[item.id].push({name: item.name, color:item.color});

    if (maxId < item.id){
        maxId = item.id;
    }
}
```

Then for your `d3`

```
//Make an SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200);

for (var i = 1; i <= maxId; i++){

    console.log("length of groupId is " + groupId[i].length);
    console.log("Id is " + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < groupId[i].length; j++){
         console.log("name is " + groupId[i][j].name + " color is " + groupId[i][j].color);
    }
    console.log("===========================");
 //Draw the Rectangle
 var rectangle = svgContainer
                 .append("rect")
                 .attr("x", i*10)
                 .attr("y", i)
                 .attr("width", 5)
                 .attr("height", groupId[i].length);
}
```

Check the console log, will help you understand the array better.

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/6DwLM/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping there might be some way of doing this grouping on the fly, without creating a new array. That's because I want to use the existing array for another part of the visualization and wanted to avoid creating several versions of the data. But if there's not a way to do that, your solution will certainly work. Much appreciated.

Comment: In fact, why not just use the object count instead of the id count? Then it would not need to do the grouping. I would guess the result is the same.

Comment: Not sure what you're suggesting. You mean just count all the objects in `data`?

Comment: Yes. counting the objects in the `data`. If every objects inside the `data` has an `id`. Then the total count for your `id` would certainly equal to the total count of your objects

Comment: Well, what I want is the total count of objects with a certain `id`. So that I can draw a bar that corresponds to the number of objects with a certain `id`. (Multiple objects can have the same `id`—it's not a unique identifier).

Comment: In my data, there might be 35 objects with `id` of 1. Another 40 with `id` of 2, etc.

Comment: Oh ya.. I forgot there is a need for you to identify the `id` within the data. Ok.. have fun with your application...^^